# load all scanner devices?

Tags: c#-4.0, device-driver, image-scanner

hi really i need help in this
i typed this code to load all connected scanner device to acombobox
but it work in windows 7 in windows xp i got this noisy exception

Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00020819-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80040154.

this is my code

```
public static void LoadScanners(ComboBox c)
   {
       MC.enableWIA();
       string deviceName = "";
       c.Items.Clear();

       WIA.DeviceManager deviceManager = new WIA.DeviceManagerClass();
       // Loop through the list of devices and add the name to the combobox

       foreach (WIA.DeviceInfo info in deviceManager.DeviceInfos )
       {
           if (info.Type == WIA.WiaDeviceType.ScannerDeviceType)
           {
               foreach (WIA.Property p in info.Properties)
               {
                   if (p.Name == "Name")
                   {
                       deviceName = ((WIA.IProperty)p).get_Value().ToString();
                       c.Items.Add(deviceName);
                   }
               }
           }


       }
   }
```

exception occur at this line

```
 WIA.DeviceManager deviceManager = new WIA.DeviceManagerClass();
```

Comment: WIA doesn't exist on Windows XP until SP3. If you're running an earlier version, it's simply not there. It's also possible that you're requesting WIA 2.0's GUID, which doesn't exist until Vista - see [MSDN here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg463512.aspx).

Comment: thanks for replay
but give me any suggestions pleaze to retrieve all scanners?

Comment: I knew why you might be getting the exception, and I explained that; I don't have an answer to your question about listing the scanners without WIA, so I didn't post an answer - I posted a comment instead.

Comment: any case thanks 4 replay